# FullPage.js "moving" position of absoluted elements

Tags: fullpage.js

I have problem with fullpage js, situation is:

in full page content there is element with styling for example:

```
.element{
    left: auto;
    right: 5vw;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: 15vh;
    transform: none;
}
```

When page is load (with this section anchor or no ) div looks like for about 100px more to bottom as it should be. When this first section is scrolled down and then back to top position of this element looks as it should be.

I know that element is in same position as in code, but don't know why looks more to bottom before first scroll.

I was also try with min-height and padding:15vh 0 but usucessfuly:/

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

solution was to adding height 100vh to parent element of this absolute element. In my case slick slider.